# Geogebra and nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I installed GeoGebra 6 from PPA. If I use it with the NVIDIA driver (version 390), I cannot use the 3D view, as it's not shown in the main menu.

When I launch `geogebra-classic` from terminal, I receive the following alert:

```
../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:seccomp-bpf failure in syscall 0230
```

With the nouveau driver the 3D view is OK, but I get other problems with two displays. In particular, when I disconnect the laptop from the second display.

Nvidia card: GeForce GT 525M/PCIe/SSE2 with optimus
Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: you should use version 455 of nvidia driver

Comment: @NinePlusTenEqualsTwentyOne Not all adapters can be used with the 455.